# jQuery filter function not working

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm trying to change the background color of all the divs which have a distance of 100px or more relative to their parent's top.

I'm using:

```
$('.box').filter(function () {
    return $(this).position.top > 99;
}).css('background', 'red');
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/68LQD/4/

Comment: position is a method, not a property

Comment: could you use a $.each() on the .box class? Where a simple if statement should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function `position`. You left off the `()`.

`position().top > 99;`

Complete code:

```
$('.box').filter(function () {
    return $(this).position().top > 99;
}).css('background', 'red');
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/KCxX5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle : [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/68LQD/8/)

Try

`$(this).positon().top` for relative to parent

`$(this).offset().top` for relative to document : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/68LQD/5/)

Comment: offset is relative to document, not parent